# how to select a multiple column value corresponding to one column value given in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I have a pandas dataframe below:

```
ID     FName   Lname    Email       DOB        Giga    Gender   status
1      Son      kam     fg@m.com    7/23/1957  nom      0        Active
2      Mum      Dar     Mdr@g.com   1/6/1988    fl      1        Inactive
3      doly     kar     dlk@f.com   12/8/1985   fg      0        Active
```

If user will enter a Id type how to get the corresponding specific column values eg: cust name = Fname "" lname, email, if gender is 0 means male else female, get the age calculate by using DOB, status  is active then satus is  "live" else dead.

and one more data frame is below:

```
ID  A   B   C
1   pm cm   mm
2   kl mk   fl
and so on.....
```

and for that ID corresponding value of all A, B, C will be output.

and some extra random values like mortage, money will be random output

mortage = random.randint(0,2)

**Can we make it generic function so that it can be applied on any dataset**

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Can you please give a sample output?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you want a function to return all other values from same row, given a specific ID. This can be achieved with the following, assuming that ID column values are unique:

```
def other_values(id, df):
    l=list(df.columns)
    l.remove('ID')
    return dict(df[df.ID==id][l].iloc[0])
```